# Applying an operation to every dataframe in the global environment

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, global, r-mice

I would like to create a prediction matrix (using mice) for each dataframe in my workspace. I thought of doing the following:

```
library(mice)
PredMatr = list()
try (for (i in 1:length(ls()))  {
  PredMatr [[i]]=quickpred(get(ls()[i]), mincor=.1)
})
```

But it stops when it encounters something different than a dataframe in the workspace. How could I adapt my code to make the operation conditional on the object being a dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `eapply` to test which objects in the environment are class `data.frame` and only work with those. For example use:

```
Myls<-ls(sorted=F)[eapply(.GlobalEnv, class)=="data.frame"]
```

and now `Myls` is a list of the names of the objects that are a `data.frame`. These can then be fed into `get()`

`eapply` is like `lapply` but it applies to every object in an environment rather than every object in a list.

**Edit to add:**
To use this in the original problem you can do the following:

```
library(mice)
PredMatr = list()
Myls<-ls(sorted=F)[eapply(.GlobalEnv, class)=="data.frame"]
try (for (i in 1:length(Myls))  {
  PredMatr [[i]]=quickpred(get(Myls[i]), mincor=.1)
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you elaborate on how to use the 'get' function in my formula?

Comment: Thank you John Paul! For some reason the solution keeps giving the same error. I cannot really see what would be the problem. The solution provided by Mr. Zen below did work.

Comment: I checked and the non-dataframes still appear in `Myls` apparently.

Comment: Nevermind - issue is that `ls()` and `eapply` puts everything in different orders, updated to keep `ls()` from alphabetizing the names. I added `sorted=F` to the `ls()` functions.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Accepted this answer as it is now slightly preferable to Mr. Zen's answer, as that one does not create a clean list (with only prediction matrices) but also with NULL values. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could add

```
if(!is.data.frame(get(ls()[i]))) next;
```

to your code, then the loop will skip to the next iteration when it encounters a non-data.frame structure.

**Answer to comment**

```
library(mice)
PredMatr = list()
try (for (i in 1:length(ls()))  {

  if(!is.data.frame(get(ls()[i]))) next;

  PredMatr [[i]]=quickpred(get(ls()[i]), mincor=.1)
})
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! This is going to sound really stupid, but how should I put it in (I did not completely come up with the solution above myself).?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!